# What happens when a magnet is dropped through a solenoid with a current running through it?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know when a magnet is dropped through a copper tube or a copper solenoid it induces a current in the copper and the magnet actually slows down as it falls through the tube, but if I did this with a solenoid that has current flowing through it, what would happen? Would there be some kind of interference since there is already a current but as the magnet falls it's supposed to induce one as well?

I'm trying to design an experiment but I'm not sure if this is something that can be investigated or if the current/magnetic field simply cancels out if you do this.

My knowledge of physics is only high school (12th grade) and perhaps somewhat college level so please explain in simple terms if possible. Thanks!

Comment: The magnet would experience a torque and forces by the field of the solenoid and the voltage on the solenoid would change by the induction voltage term due to the changing magnetic flux. If the permanent magnet is small compared to the solenoid and has a reasonable approximation by a dipole field, then we can model all of this with the interaction of the dipole with the solenoid field. If that's not the case, we may have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: This should mean though that the magnet changes speed as it falls through the solenoid right?

Comment: Yes, it would rotate and be pulled into the coil. If you prevent the rotation, you can either get attraction or repulsion. In essence, the coil behaves in a very similar way to a large permanent magnet, except that it is empty on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of the permanent magnet is much stronger than that of the coil, hence we expect no effects from the coil onto the magnet. The coil is a linear element, so the problem becomes that of simple superposition.. that is the sum of the case of a magnet dropping inside a copper cylinder (assuming a close winding) + effect of the field from the coil onto the moving magnet.